# Could not resolve all files for configuration ':url_launcher:lintClassPath'

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, flutter

I have `flutter 1.0.0`

In my `pubspec.yaml`, I added `url_launcher: ^4.0.2`

Without importing `url_launcher`, I am getting those errors:

> Launching lib\main.dart on BBD100 2 in debug mode...
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':url_launcher:lintClassPath'.
>
>   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.2.1.   Required by:
>   >       project :url_launcher
>   >     Could not resolve com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.2.1.
>   >     Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.2.1/lint-gradle-26.2.1.pom'.
>   >     Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.2.1/lint-gradle-26.2.1.pom'.
>   >     Connect to 10.10.208.70:8080 [/10.10.208.70] failed: Connection timed out: connect
>   >     Could not resolve com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.2.1.
>   >     Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.2.1/lint-gradle-26.2.1.pom'.
>   >     Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.2.1/lint-gradle-26.2.1.pom'.
>   >     Connect to 10.10.208.70:8080 [/10.10.208.70] failed: Connection timed out: connect
>   >     Could not resolve com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.2.1.
>   >     Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.2.1/lint-gradle-26.2.1.pom'.
>   >     Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.2.1/lint-gradle-26.2.1.pom'.
>   >     Connect to 10.10.208.70:8080 [/10.10.208.70] failed: Connection timed out: connect
>   >     Could not resolve com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.2.1.
>   >     Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.2.1/lint-gradle-26.2.1.pom'.
>   >     Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.2.1/lint-gradle-26.2.1.pom'.
>   >     Connect to 10.10.208.70:8080 [/10.10.208.70] failed: Connection timed out: connect
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 1m 33s Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code
>   1 Exited (sigterm)

Anyone can help me to debug that issue?

I tried reinstalling Flutter without any success.

Flutter doctor did not detect anything wrong.

Thanks in advance!

*** How can I use --stacktrace, --info or --debug options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try moving `maven_url / google()` on top of `jcenter()` inside

> C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle.

Comment: Hi @rahul.sharma. The maven_url is not present in that file. Only google(), then jcenter(). I am not sure, but I think maven_url is not needed with Flutter, no?

Comment: Guess what? After my second reboot, no more error! I am a bit lost, but now it is working! Thanks anyway for your input.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the steps,

- flutter clean
- flutter pub get
- flutter run